# Unwanted Image Resizing in Bitmap to ImageSource

Tags: image, bitmap, size, emgucv, imagesource

I'm programming by WPF(c#) for image processing (in emgu cv). In my application, I open a image using these codes:

```
OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();

if(d.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(d.FileName);
    img1.Source = Util.Convert(b);
}
```

I use codes below to convert `Bitmap` to `ImageSource` and vice versa:

```
public static Bitmap ImageSourceToBitmap(ImageSource imageSource)
{
    BitmapSource bitmapSource = (BitmapSource)imageSource;

    MemoryStream mse = new MemoryStream();
    BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
    encoder.Save(mse);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(mse);

    return bitmap;
}

public static BitmapImage Convert(Bitmap src)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)src).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    image.StreamSource = ms;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```

Size of image will be changed (a strange behavior is occurred on my conversion) when i use it from a button. the code event of button is:

```
Image<Gray, byte> im = new Image<Gray, byte>(Util.ImageSourceToBitmap(img1.Source));
im._EqualizeHist();

img1.Source = Util.Convert(im.Bitmap);
```

I also set `stretch = None`.

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What are you displaying the image on? That might be giving you some resizing. I typically use a canvas and scaling so my image is always the same size.

You conversions look 'odd' to me. Try the methods here: [Convert Bitmaps](https://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/Emgu.CV.WPF/BitmapSourceConverter.cs)

Since a BitmapImage is a derivitive of a BitmapSource this should work fine for you. I suspect it will be faster as well.

Doug